# Why am i always getting Group C

Tags: python

Question:

Display the message Group A if a string contains at least one letter A,
either in uppercase or lowercase in the last 3 positions of the string.
Display Group B if a string contains the letter B, either in uppercase or
lowercase in all last three positions. Display the message Group C
otherwise. Do not use loop/repetition structure. Use the slice operator.

My code:

```
s = input('Enter string: ')
if 'Aa' in s[-3:]:
    print('Group A')
elif 'Bb' in s[-3] and 'Bb' in s[-2] and 'Bb' in s[-1]:
    print('Group B')
else:
    print('Group C')
```

Comment: You need to find if `A` or `a` are in the substring, not `Aa`

Comment: your `if` condition is comparing `Aa` not just `A` or `a`, which means it checking if a string contains `Aa` and `Bb`. So if your input doesn't contain `Aa` or `Bb` then it definitely return `Group C`

Comment: `'Bb' in s[-3]` will always be`False` because `'Bb'` is 2 characters and `s[-3]` is only one. Did you maybe mean `s[-3:]`?

Answer (score 0):

`'Aa' in 'ABC'` will return `False`. The `in` operator in this context well check if the exact full substring (not any individual characters) is present.

In your case, you need to check each character individually, or convert the case to use a single character.

You can use:

```
s = input('Enter string: ')
if 'A' in s[-3:].upper():
    print('Group A')
elif 'BBB' == s[-3:].upper():
    print('Group B')
else:
    print('Group C')
```

Or better, slice and convert the case only once:

```
s = input('Enter string: ')[-3:].upper()
if 'A' in s:
    print('Group A')
elif 'BBB' == s:
    print('Group B')
else:
    print('Group C')
``
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may think you're using Regex, to actually use it:

```
import re

s = input('Enter string: ')
if re.match('[Aa]', s):
    print('Group A')
...
```